# Ionic2/Angular2: Where can I update a users last access timestamp?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 rc4.

I have a function that updates a users **last access timestamp**.

I need to execute this function each time the app is accessed. Is there somewhere I can do this call?

I thought about doing the call in the `app.component.ts` in the `platform.ready().then(() => {...}`, but I think this only gets invoked once when the app starts up, and won't get invoked again unless the app is killed.

Thanks

Comment: Well, unless the app is killed, the app doesn't start up again. So it will be quite hard trying to validate *'each time the app is accessed'* but if this is what you want you could place your function in a Service and just call it from each page's `ngOnInit` or `constructor`

Comment: I suspected as much, but was hoping it was not the case. I think I will need to do exactly what you say. Thank you

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure, you could try changing this question to [angular2] and asking for 'calling a function from every component'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
  this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
    //App paused or closed
  });

  this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
    //App resumed or start
  });
});
```

put this code inside your MyApp constructor.